# Unity touch not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hey I am having issues with unity accepting touch registration. The program I am creating needs to be able to register touches on a specific item, in a sea of items blocking it. At the moment Unity is not registering my touches as I have tried to print out messages to see where it ends and it does not register the touch. Any help with fixing my code would be greatly appreciated. PS: The code is written in Javascript.

```
    #pragma strict
var target: GameObject;
var SpawnPoint: Transform;
var TargetCollider : BoxCollider;
var hit : RaycastHit;
var clone: GameObject;

function Start () {

    var x = Random.Range(-14,17);
    var y = Random.Range(-6,9);
    var z = Random.Range(2,3);
    SpawnPoint.position = Vector3(x,y,0);
    yield WaitForSeconds(5);
    clone = Instantiate(target, SpawnPoint.position, SpawnPoint.rotation);  
}

function Update () 
{
            /*
            if (Input.GetTouch(0))  
            {

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
            var hit = RaycastHit;
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            TargetCollider = target.GetComponent(BoxCollider);

            if (collider.Raycast(ray, RaycastHit, 100.00f)) {
                if (hit.collider != null)
                {
                    Destroy(clone);
                    Application.LoadLevel("Splash Screen Win");
                }   

            }
        }   

}
*/
                var tapCount = Input.touchCount;
                for (var i = 0; i < tapCount; i++)
                {
                var touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
                var hit : RaycastHit;
                if (Physics.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position)))
                {
                    print("test"); 
                    /*if (hit.collider != null)
                    {
                    Destroy(clone);
                    Application.LoadLevel("Splash Screen Win");
                    }*/
                }


                }



}
```

Comment: Does the object you want to touch have a collider component? Make sure it is not set to trigger mode (or if it is, enable "raycasts hit triggers" in physics options).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`function Update () 
{

```
            var tapCount = Input.touchCount;
            for (var i = 0; i < tapCount; i++)
            {

            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            var hit : RaycastHit;
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, 100))
            {
                print("test"); 

            }


            }
```

}`

You might need to place the intended target object on a separate layer so you can specifically raycast on that layer and ignore the other objects on different layers.

[Check out how to create layer masks](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/Layers.html)

Comment: How is this different from the original code in the question? It only limits the ray distance from `Mathf.Infinity` to `100`.

Comment: I guess the only difference is that the method I used returns a ray variable that contains all the colliders it has hit.

Comment: No it doesn't, the ray is just a point and a direction. `Physics.Raycast` as you use it returns a boolean. The RaycastHit variable is unused.

Comment: used or unused, the variable is there which wasn't in the original code